# Sending Spotify Backstage logs to a fluentd server

Tags: backstage

I'm evaluating the usage of Spotify Backstage.
Looking at the documentation, I see that it uses the `winston` library for logging.
Do you know if there is a way to send these logs to a fluentd server? and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.

1. I installed the `fluent-logger` package to the Backstage backend.
2. I put this code into the `packages/backend/src/index.ts` file

```
const fluentTransport = new FluentTransport({
  host: 'host',
  port: 24224 ,
  timeout: 3.0,
  requireAckResponse: true,
});

root.add(fluentTransport);
```

to add the transport to the logger.

Because I'm using Docker, I also create a `docker-compose.yml` file to run the services

**docker-compose.yml**

```
backstage:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: <path_to_Dockerfile>
    image: <image_name>
    container_name: <container_name>
    environment:
      FLUENTD_HOST: fluentd
      FLUENTD_PORT: 24224    
    ------
  fluentd:
    image: fluent/fluentd:v1.16.1-1.0
    container_name: fluentd
    volumes:
      - <path_to_local_fluentd_configuration>:/fluentd/fluent.conf
    command: ["-c", "/fluentd/fluent.conf"]
    ports:
      - 24224:24224
      - 5140:5140
```

and I also create a custom fluent.conf to let fluentd start tracing the logs from Backstage.

**fluent.conf**

```
<source>
  @type forward
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 24224
</source>

<match  **.*>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

Hope this can help you.